# Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges. Let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $m \ge 2e/n$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges. Let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $m \ge 2e/n$.
Prove that $G$ has a vertex of degree at least $m$.

My approach is sum of all the degree of a graph is $2e$.
$d(v_1)+d(v_2)+......+d(v_n)=2e$.
then if we take the average, will get
$d(v)=2e/n$.
now this will be in between minimum degree and maximum degree in the graph.
Now $m$ also lies in between maximum and minimum degree of the graph.
From here how can we conclude the answer.
Please help me.

Comment: Hello. Since you are new, I have a little advice. I just edited your question. See how nice your formulas look? You can do the same too! Just put your formulas between dollar signs and format them with LaTeX next time.

Comment: ok. Thank you @ZeroXLR

Comment: @user279783: What does **+ve** mean?

Comment: I'm assuming it is short hand for "positive".

Answer (score 1):

Now it's just a property of averages:

> If $S$ is a finite set of integers, then $\max(S) \geq \lceil \mathrm{ave}(S) \rceil$.

*Proof*: If $S=\{s_i\}_{i=1}^n$, then
\begin{align*}
\max(S) & = \frac{\overbrace{\max(S)+\max(S)+\cdots+\max(S)}^{n \text{ times}}}{n} \\
 & \geq \frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n} & \text{since each } s_i \leq \max(S) \\
 & = \mathrm{ave}(S) & \text{by definition}.
\end{align*}
And since $\max(S)$ is an integer, then $\max(S) \geq \lceil \mathrm{ave}(S) \rceil$.

In this case, we have $S$ as the set of degrees, and we can choose $m$ equal to the maximum degree, i.e., $m=\max(S)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there does not exist a vertex $v$ such that $\deg(v) \geq m$. Then the sum of the degrees of all vertices in $G$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_i \leq (m-1)n$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_i=2e$, we have $2e\leq(m-1)n$. Divide both sides by $n$ to get $\frac{2e}{n} \leq m-1$. So, we have $\frac{2e}{n}+1 \leq m$. This is a contradiction because if $\frac{2e}{n}$ is an integer, then $m=\frac{2e}{n}$ and if $\frac{2e}{n}$ is not an integer, $m=\frac{2e}{n}+c$ for some rational number $0<c<1$.

Comment: what does it mean "since 2e/n=2e"?

Comment: please explain last sentence. i am not getting the contradiction logic.

Comment: I fixed my typo (I did this very late last night), sorry about that. $m$ cannot be $\frac{2e}{n}+1$ or greater because it is the smallest integer satisfying $m \geq \frac{2e}{n}$, and would be rounded down if it was indeed $\frac{2e}{n}+1$. Try a few examples by choosing values for $n$ and $e$. Hopefully this clears things up.